# Hibernate with oracle sequence is Not working at all

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sequence

```
sequence:    
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_userId
 START WITH     100001
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

Entity Bean is defined as below:
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

```
@Column(name="user_id", length=6, unique=true)
@SequenceGenerator(name="requestId",sequenceName="sequence_userId",     allocationSize=1, initialValue=100001)
@GeneratedValue(generator="requestId",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int userId;
```

But when i am executing the program, the userId inserted in Table is '0'.
I am using Oracle DB 10g. hibernate is not picking the sequence from Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer as why it is not Working..
In JPA/Hibernate... GeneratedValue will work only with @Id annotation..
as in this case the user_id column is not primary key, its not working here...